# Flutter, how to disable the horizontal swipe inside TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class returning `GestureDetector` and inside it I control horizontal swiping. If swiped left I move to another screen and if swipe right I move to another one. This pages I am moving are the children of this class. The problem is, these pages have `TextFormField`s inside them and when I type something in fields and try to select the text, gesture detector is detecting it as a swipe and swiping to another screen instead of selecting the text. What I want is keeping the `TextFormField`s out of that detector. My main page codes are:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  SwipeController swipeController = Get.put(SwipeController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      return GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
            setState(() {
              swipeController.index.value = 0;
            });
          } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
            setState(() {
              swipeController.index.value = 1;
            });
          }
        },
        child: swipeController.index.value == 0 ? AuthorPage() : DesignerPage(),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

**AuthorPage()** and **DesignerPage()** are the pages which have `TextFormField`s. When swiping happens, screen moves to them. And these pages are classic returning `Scaffold` pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing a FocusNode object inside the focusNode parameter of the TextFormField? Does that solve your case?

```
TextFormField(
    focusNode: FocusNode(canRequestFocus: false),
),
```

From Flutter documentation [canRequestFocus property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode/canRequestFocus.html):

> Defaults to true. Set to false if you want this node to do nothing when requestFocus is called on it.
> If set to false on a FocusScopeNode, will cause all of the children of the scope node to not be focusable.

Comment: I just tried it, still swiping when I try to select text. TextFormFiled is still a part of GestureDetector.

Comment: Can you try setting: ```descendantsAreFocusable```, ```descendantsAreTraversable``` to false, and ```skipTraversal``` to true?

Comment: That did not work too. I am not sure the solution is about focus nodes because gesture detector is wrapping whole page.

Comment: Would you want a solution where you'd be able to swipe in the whole page BUT the TextFormField's?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I can change my structure to do that but I wondered a solution without changing the structure.

Comment: With GestureDetector wrapping the whole page, I don't think you'd have better luck than just having a Stack and doing things that way :).

Comment: Yes, looks like I need to change my structure, thanks for your interest.